# Withdrawal method in Online Banking Web Service not working

Tags: java, mysql, web-services

I am currently creating a web service for online banking, but my withdrawal method doesnt seem to be working. The withdrawal is supposed to take the amount specified from the Current Balance column with the account id specified.

Here is my code...

**Accounts.java:**

```
   package com.banking.entity;


    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import static javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement(name = "accounts")
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "accounts")
    public class Account implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "Account_ID")
        private int Account_ID;
        @Column(name = "Sort_Code")
        private int Sort_Code;
        @Column(name = "Account_No")
        private int Account_No;
        @Column(name = "Current_Balance")
        private double Current_Balance;
        @Column(name = "Customer_ID")
        private int Customer_ID;

        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        private Collection<Transaction> transaction = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

        public Collection<Transaction> getTransactions() {
            return transaction;
        }

        public void setTransactions(Collection<Transaction> transaction) {
            this.transaction = transaction;
        }

        @XmlAttribute
        public int getCustomer_ID() {
            return Customer_ID;
        }

        public void setCustomer_ID(int Customer_ID) {
            this.Customer_ID = Customer_ID;
        }

        @XmlAttribute
        public int getId() {
            return Account_ID;
        }

        public void setId(int Account_ID) {
            this.Account_ID = Account_ID;
        }

        @XmlAttribute
        public int getSortCode() {
            return Sort_Code;
        }

        public void setSortCode(int Sort_Code) {
            this.Sort_Code = Sort_Code;
        }

        @XmlAttribute
        public int getAccountNo() {
            return Account_No;
        }

        public void setAccountNo(int Account_No) {
            this.Account_No = Account_No;
        }

        @XmlAttribute
        public double getCurrentBalance() {
            return Current_Balance;
        }

        public void setCurrentBalance(double Current_Balance) {
            this.Current_Balance = Current_Balance;
        }



        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Account{" + "Account_ID=" + Account_ID + ", Sort_Code=" + Sort_Code + ", Account_No=" + Account_No + ", Current_Balance=" + Current_Balance + ", Customer_ID=" + Customer_ID + '}';
        }




    }
```

**AccountsResource.java:**

```
    package com.banking.resource;

    import com.banking.entity.Account;
    import com.banking.entity.Customer;
    import com.banking.entity.Transaction;
    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import static java.util.Collections.singletonList;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.naming.NamingException;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
    import javax.persistence.Persistence;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    @Path("/accounts")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public  class AccountResource extends ResourceBase<Account> {

        private EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Banking");
        private EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        private EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        private List<Account> listAccounts;

        @Override
        protected List<Account> getMultiQuery() throws NamingException {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            listAccounts = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Account e").getResultList();
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
            return listAccounts;
        }

        @Override
        protected List getSingleQuery(int id) throws NamingException {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            listAccounts = singletonList(em.find(Account.class, id));
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
            return listAccounts;
        }

        @Override
        protected List getAccountBalance(int id) throws NamingException {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            listAccounts = singletonList(em.find(Account.class, id));
            Account a = new Account();
            a.getCurrentBalance();
            em.persist(a);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
            return listAccounts;
        }

        @Override
        protected void createAccount(Account t) throws SQLException, NamingException {
            //Account acc = new Account();
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            t.setSortCode(t.getSortCode());
            t.setAccountNo(t.getAccountNo());
            t.setCurrentBalance(t.getCurrentBalance());
            t.setCustomer_ID(t.getCustomer_ID());
            em.persist(t);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
        }

    //    public void transfer(Account from, Account to, double amount) throws NamingException {
    //        em = getEntityManager();
    //        em.getTransaction().begin();
    //        Account f = em.find(Account.class, from.getId());
    //        Account t = em.find(Account.class, to.getId());
    //        f.getCurrentBalance() - amount;
    //        t.setCurrentBalance() + amount;
    //          em.getTransaction().commit();
    //          em.close();
    //    }

        //@Override
        protected Account withdraw(
                @PathParam("id") int id,
                @PathParam("amount") int amount, Account b) throws NamingException {
             em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Account test = em.find(Account.class, b.getId());
            if (test != null) {
                Account a1 = new Account();
                double balance = a1.getCurrentBalance();
                double bal = balance - amount;
                a1.setCurrentBalance(bal);
                em.remove(test);
                em.persist(a1);
                tx.commit();
                em.close();
            }

            return b;
        }

        @Override
        protected void deleteQuery(int id) throws SQLException, NamingException {
            Account acc = new Account();
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            acc = em.find(Account.class, id);
            em.remove(acc);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateQuery(Account t, int id) throws SQLException, NamingException {
            //Account acc = new Account();
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            t = em.find(Account.class, id);
            t.setSortCode(t.getSortCode());
            t.setAccountNo(t.getAccountNo());
            t.setCurrentBalance(t.getCurrentBalance());
            t.setCustomer_ID(t.getCustomer_ID());
            em.persist(t);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
        }

        @Override
        protected void createCustomer(Customer t) throws SQLException, NamingException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        protected void createTransaction(Transaction t) throws SQLException, NamingException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        protected List withdraw(int id, double amount) throws NamingException {
            return null;        
        }

    }
```

**ResourceBase.java:**

```
    package com.banking.resource;

    import com.banking.entity.Account;
    import com.banking.entity.Customer;
    import com.banking.entity.Transaction;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.naming.NamingException;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.persistence.Persistence;
    import javax.ws.rs.*;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    @Produces("application/xml")

    public abstract class ResourceBase<T> {

        protected abstract List getMultiQuery() throws SQLException, NamingException;

        protected abstract List getSingleQuery(int id) throws NamingException;

        protected abstract List withdraw(int id, double amount) throws NamingException;

        protected abstract List getAccountBalance(int id) throws NamingException;

        protected abstract void createCustomer(Customer t) throws SQLException, NamingException;

        protected abstract void createAccount(Account t) throws SQLException, NamingException;

        protected abstract void createTransaction(Transaction t) throws SQLException, NamingException;

        protected abstract void deleteQuery(int id) throws SQLException, NamingException;

        protected abstract void updateQuery(T t, int id) throws SQLException, NamingException;

        protected static EntityManager getEntityManager() throws NamingException {
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Banking");
            return emf.createEntityManager();
        }

        @GET
        public List<T> getList() throws SQLException, NamingException {
            List records = getMultiQuery();
            return records;
        }

        @GET
        @Path("{id}")
        public List<T> getSingle(@PathParam("id") int id) throws NamingException {
            List records = getSingleQuery(id);
            return records;
        }
        @PUT
        @Path("{id}/{amount}")
        public List<T> makeWithdrawal(@PathParam("id") int id, @PathParam("amount") double amount) throws NamingException {
            List records = withdraw(id, amount);
            return records;
        }

        @GET
        @Path("/{id}/balance")
        public List<T> getBalance(@PathParam("id") int id) throws NamingException {
           List records = getAccountBalance(id);
            return records;
        }

        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Path("/savecustomer")
        public void insertCustomer(Customer t) throws NamingException, SQLException {
            createCustomer(t);
        }

        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Path("/saveaccount")
        public void insertAccount(Account t) throws NamingException, SQLException {
            createAccount(t);
        }

        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Path("/addTransaction")
        public void addTransaction(Transaction t) throws NamingException, SQLException {
            createTransaction(t);
        }

        @DELETE
        @Path("delete/{id}")
        public void delete(@PathParam("id") int id) throws SQLException, NamingException {
            deleteQuery(id);
        }

    }
```

And the Accounts table in MySQL:

[image: accounts]

Comment: *Doesn't seem to be working*? what happens?

Comment: Postman returns the following:  204 No Content:
The server successfully processed the request, but is not returning any content.

Comment: Are you asking about `makeWithdrawal`? The implementation calls `withdraw` that returns always null

Comment: Yes, makeWithdrawal is what Im trying to get working.